# How to keep origin value (datetime type) when querying on mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below is the DateTime stored in my database.
[image]

But when I query then it auto-converts and cast to my model with my current time-zone

[image]

My expected is to keep the origin value that is stored on my DB after querying

Comment: I think its a string representation of the datetime object. The output shown is dependent upon the tool or programming language you use to print / display the data - it can be different for each.

Comment: Hi @prasad_ 
The data type of these fields is Date type

Comment: What do intend to do with that date data (after you query it)?

Comment: I don't do anything... the results auto transform with the current time-zone